# Weird behaviour of FindMinimum

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

On Mathematica 12.1, I tried to do

```
FindMinimum[Sin[x] + 1, {x, 55.00000000000001`, 54, 56},  Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]
```

It gives the output

> `FindMinimum::fddis`: The starting values `` 55.00000000000001` ``  and `` 55.` `` 
> are not sufficiently distinct to begin a search.
> ...
> `General::stop`: Further output of `FindMinimum::fddis` will be suppressed
> during this calculation.

and no result returned.

However,

```
FindMinimum[Sin[x] + 1, {x, 55.0000000000000`, 54, 56}, Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]
```

has no problem to get

```
{0., {x -> 54.9779}}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I tried it using "11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)" and it gives the same error and the same answer when I executed the second command. Just pointing this out.

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 Thanks for testing :)

Comment: Use higher precision: `FindMinimum[
 Sin[x] + 1, {x, SetPrecision[55.00000000000001\`, 20], 54, 56}, Method -> "PrincipalAxis", WorkingPrecision -> 20]` or `FindMinimum[Sin[x] + 1, {x, SetPrecision[55.00000000000001\`, 20], 54, 56}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks for suggestion. I now prefer shifting the starting point a little while still keep it in the range. Higer orkingPrecision will cause computation slower

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FindMinimum` seems to automatically choose the midpoint for a second starting point to specify the search direction (see [tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationMethodsForLocalMinimization.html#188073100)).  But the midpoint differs from the specified starting point by one bit. Therefore `55.00000000000001 == 55.` is true since the default `` Internal`$EqualTolerance `` (`2.10721` = `Log10[2.^7]`) specifies that two machine reals are equal if they agree up to the last 7 bits.

When you specify the midpoint `55.0000000000000`, then `FindMinimum` finds another starting point.  I don't know why they didn't think to do that in the first case.

*Some evidence to back up the analysis above:*

Changing `` Internal`$EqualTolerance `` to zero fixes the problem.

```
Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0},
 FindMinimum[Sin[x] + 1, {x, 55.00000000000001`, 54, 56}, 
  Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]
 ]
```

Changing an endpoint by a sufficient amount fixes the problem.

```
FindMinimum[Sin[x] + 1, {x, 55.00000000000001`, 54, 56.0001}, 
 Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]
```

Comment: Hi, Michael E2. Thank you so much for quick analysis and workaround. I actually don't quite understand the algorithm of "PrincipalAxis". Yet here is another case `FindMinimum[x^2, {x, 2, 1, 3}, Method -> "PrincipalAxis"]` I do not understand. It show message " Reached the point {-1.33227*10^-15}, which is outside the region {{1.},{3.}}.". If mathematica knows it is out of range, why not just stop at 1? I thought this syntax would guarantee a result within range.

Comment: @matheorem I'd send that one into WRI and ask them to change `"PrincpalAxis"` to behave like `FindMinimum[x^2, {x, 2, 1, 3}]`.  I doubt there's a good reason for the way they programmed it that way.  (It would be ok with me if they gave the warning message, but it also return the result.)

Comment: That will be good. So is there a workaround now? I found "PrincpalAxis" method is good, it seems that it is often faster.

Comment: Oh, I just found setting Internal`$EqualTolerance = 0 is not good. It will give `{0.000244827, {x -> 55.}}`, however, 0.000244827 should be almost 0.

Comment: @matheorem I guess the step size at the beginning is so small the stopping criteria are satisfied. Interesting comparison: Startting at `55 + 0.00000000000001` vs. `55 - 0.00000000000001`.  There can be tremendous round-off errors when computing differences with small steps, and it's just a guess that it's a factor.